# How to I get this type of mesh in Blender?

Tags: mesh, node-editor, geometry-nodes, volumetrics

[image]I created this mesh in Cinema 4d, making use of Shader field and volume mesher:
[image: I created this mesh in Cinema 4d, making use of Shader field and volume mesher.]

I am trying to recreate this type of mesh "(liquid)" in Blender. I first try by using geometry nodes, by converting the mesh to volume, then, converting it back to mesh, next, trying to delete the mesh but just the outer faces got deleted.[image] I am new user of Blender and I don't know much about the logic behind the geometry nodes.

Comment: Hello ! I think the go-to addon to achieve this kind of result is the By-Gen addon by Curtis Holt. You can study the node trees and modifier stacks after applying an effect to see how it's done. Usually it's a mix of voronoi / noise / displacement / boolean https://curtisholt.online/by-gen. There is a free version.

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thank you, for your feedback! I appreciated so much. I am new in this forum, I am going to make the changes you told me to. Thanks again!<3